# Limit object count in foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, object, foreach, count

Here is my loop

```
$i=0;
foreach($last5 as $last){
  if($uid['urels_id'] != $last->urels_id ){ 
    $i=0;
  }
  $uid = array('urels_id' => $last->urels_id, 'count' => $i);

  if( $uid['count'] <= 4 && $uid['urels_id'] == $last->urels_id ){
    $last_five['last5'][] = array('urels_id' => $last->urels_id, 'url' => $last->url, 'title' =>    $last->title, 'sent' => $last->sent);
  }
  else {  
    continue; 
  }

  $i++;
  array_push($gcntd, $last_five);

}
```

What i'm trying to produce, is to limit each id to 5. Each urels_id may have 100s of results and I only want the last 5. SQL query limit is not an option.

it does return properly but returns all results

here is a sample

```
[last5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [urels_id] => 17366
                [url] => /evl/reb/4575464991.html
                [title] => Beautiful Remodel in Scottsdale (Scottsdale) $645000 4bd 2843sqft
                [sent] => 2014-08-01 21:57:07
            )
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of how many times an ID's been encountered?

```
$ids = array();
foreach($arr as $item) {
    $ids[$item['id']]++; // increment id counter
    if ($ids[$item['id']] < 5) {
         ... do something ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Life saver! spent 2 days trying to figure that out. Just a note for some reason I had to change the 5 to 6 to get the 5 count. No biggy works! Thank you!